# Uniqueness of a number $area(A)$

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, area

I have the following definition of area:

Let $A$ be a bounded set from $\mathbb{R}^2$. We say that $A$ has area if there exist two sequences $(E_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, (F_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elementar sets, such that:
 - (*1*) $E_n \subset A \subset F_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
 - (*2*) the sequences of positive real numbers {$area(E_n)$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$,{$area(F_n)$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are convergent with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$=$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (2).

In this case, we write:

$$area(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$

Now, a set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is called **elementar** if $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^nD_i$, where $D_i$ are rectangles with the sides parralel to the axes $(Ox, Oy)$ and any two different rectangles $D_i, D_j$ have at most one common side.
We define:
$$area(E):=\sum_{i=1}^n area(D_i)$$

The book where this definitions are presented omits to prove that the definition of $area(A)$ is correct, i.e. if we pick another two sequences $(U_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(V_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that (*1*) and (*2*) are satisfied, then 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}area(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}area(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
How can one prove this? Thank you very much!

More: if $A, B$ have area, then $A\cup B,$ A\B and $A\cap B$ have area.

Answer (score 1):

Lets denote with $$a_n := area(E_n), \, b_n :=area(F_n), \, c_n=area(U_n), \, d_n=area(V_n)$$ and assume $\lim a_n = \lim b_n=:x$ and $\lim c_n = \lim d_n=:y$.

Your question is, why is $x = y $?

Because of $$E_n \subset A \subset V_n$$ we have $a_n \leq d_n$ and thus $x \leq y.$ Also we have $$U_n \subset A \subset F_n $$ which shows $c_n \leq b_n$ and thus $y \leq x$. All in all, we end up with $x=y$.

Comment: Yes, simple as that! How about my second question? :)

Comment: The problem with the second is that we cannot assume A and B are disjoint, because of A\B...

Comment: yes this I noticed that. This is why I edit it a long time ago

Comment: If you have time for the problem, give it a try! :)